# Trying to Iterate through strings to add certain characters to new string

Tags: python, string, loops, for-loop

I am trying to remove certain characters from a string and it was suggested that i try and make a new string and just add characters that meet my criteria. I use a for loop to iterate through the string but then characters arent added to the new string-it prints a blank string. Ill include an ss.

[image: the s is the original string]

Comment: Please post your code as plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the `in` operator for comparing a value with multiple other values:

```
if s[i] not in 'AEIOUaeiou' or s[i-1] == ' ':
    # if you prefer lists / tuples / sets of characters, you can use those instead:
    # if s[i] not in ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', ...]
    answer_string += s[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
answer_string += s[i]
```

As, your current statement `answer_string + s` is not doing what you are hoping for.

> This is what I understood from the given context. It would be better if you could post a code snippet with reference for better understanding the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the character with each on it's own. That would be:

```
if s[i] != "A" or s[i] != "B" ... :
```

A more elegant solution would be:

```
if s[i] not in ["ABCD..."]:
```

Also what [@avats](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9556205/avats) said, you should be adding the single character, not the whole string

```
answer_string += s[i]
```

To make the checking case insensitive, so you wouldn't have to type out all the uppercase letters and lowercase, use `lower()`:

```
if s[i].lower() not in ["abcd"]:
```